# Grounding in circuit diagrams

Tags: ground, basic

Often I see in circuit diagrams that the circuit is connected to the ground:

[image]

I understand that this creates a reference for zero potential, but why does all of the current not simply flow right into the ground?  I must have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: Kirchoff's Current Law

Comment: @MattYoung, with a bit more explanation (like "just like any other node") your comment should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current doesn't all just flow to ground because of Kirchoff's Current Law. Kirchoff's Current Law states that the sum of the currents entering and leaving a node must be equal to zero. If x amps flow from the power supply, x amps must return to the power supply.

In your schematic, before the earth connection was added, the voltages had no reference. Adding the earth connection puts the negative terminal of the supply at earth potential, making all the voltages earth referenced. If you prefer to think of it in terms of Spice, the negative terminal and earth nodes were merged. The current still has to flow back to the power supply, where it came from. Additionally, if any other point in the circuit were tied to earth, the current would still flow back to the negative terminal of the power supply through earth.

Comment: Is that a connection to Earth, the planet we live on? Or is it just a schematic symbol? In my experience, it's the latter, unless there is good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @PhilFrost, either way, current can't flow from your circuit into the earth node without equal current flowing back out into your circuit somewhere else.

Comment: That symbol is what I was taught to refer to as earth (safety) ground. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_%28electricity%29#Electronics

Comment: @MattYoung strictly speaking you aren't wrong, but in practice it's also some other (possibly galvanically isolated, arbitrary) ground quite often. I'm guilty of using it in all of my schematics that aren't necessarily Earthed, because the simple triangle symbol just looks too weird.

Comment: I'm the exact opposite, I use the triangle because the earth symbol looks weird to me. :)

Comment: @MattYoung you must be younger (no pun intended! or was it?)

Answer (score 5):

The ground symbol:

[image: ground symbol]

means, "this is connected with wire to all the other things connected to other instances of this symbol". Since there is only one of these in your example schematic, it means nothing at all in this respect.

It also might mean, "If someone gives you a voltage without an explicit reference, assume it's relative to this thing".

So it serves two goals:

1. make the schematic more readable. There are a lot of things that connect here, and without this symbol we'd have a lot more lines in a big schematic, and you'd have to follow them very far to find they just go to the power source.
2. make discussion of the circuit shorter, since we can assume a voltage reference. Since voltages are relative, we always need a reference.

Note that discussing the circuit, and making it readable, really have *nothing* to do with how the circuit operates. The electricity in the circuit cares about the ground symbol as much as it cares about the identifiers by the parts, or the title block, or the border. That is, it doesn't care at all.

What happens if we stick the ground symbol between the resistors? The voltages become:

- C = 50V
- B = 0V
- A = -25V

This doesn't change the operation of the circuit; just our discussion of it. We put the ground where it will make discussion convenient.

Comment: On top of what Phil says, if you are simulating this with Software like SPICE, you have to give it a reference from which to measure (because voltages are relative it can't know how to even start) so it can setup the circuit.  No ground -> Won't run.